# How to make multiple fetch request in a single fetch API

Tags: javascript

I have an API link where I need to check the price of certain items. For example, Only change in the fetch URL is the items. is there any easy way to do it in one fetch or using any loop?

www.apirequest/item1/ps2 
www.apirequest/item2/ps2
www.apirequest/item3/ps2
www.apirequest/item4/ps2
www.apirequest/item5/ps2

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @mplungjan, Sorry about that. I tried to search but was not sure how to even search about that. This is the start I needed to work on the stuff. I will definitely do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to pass the item name/id in body or you can also grap that from params. Then in the api point you can use fetch or axios to make api request.

```
const axios = require("axios");

app.post("/api/test", async (req, res) => {

  const { param } = req.body // you can use query params

  await axios.get(`www.apirequest/item1/${param}`).then((result)=>{
console.log(result)
})

  res.send("okay");
});
```